# Sailsjs v1 PostgreSQL many-to-many association addToCollection failing due to model validation

Tags: postgresql, many-to-many, sails.js

I use SailsJS v1 and PostgreSQL and have two models (Tickets and Records) with a many-to-many association as follows:

**`Tickets.js`**

```
/**
* Tickets.js
*
* @description :: A model definition represents a database table/collection.
* @docs        :: https://sailsjs.com/docs/concepts/models-and-orm/models */
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        errorTypeId: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        records: {
            collection: 'records',
            via: 'tickets',
            dominant: true 
        }
    },
};
```

**`Records.js`**

```
/**
* Records.js
*
* @description :: A model definition represents a database table/collection.
* @docs        :: https://sailsjs.com/docs/concepts/models-and-orm/models
*/
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        foreignId: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        tickets:  {
            collection: 'tickets',
            via: 'records'
        }
    },
};
```

In **`config/models.js`** I have added some code to handle GUID IDs automatically:

```
...
attributes: {
    createdAt: { type: 'number', autoCreatedAt: true, },
    updatedAt: { type: 'number', autoUpdatedAt: true, },
    id: { type: 'string', autoIncrement: false, required: true},
},
beforeCreate: function (modelObj, next) {
    modelObj.id = uuid.v4();
    next();
},
...
```

I have the following issues:

1. It does not seem to be possible to use `autoIncrement` with Postgres, since the database expects a specific column type, however, it's not possible to specify it. 
   1.1. Since the ORM requires either `autoIncrement` or `required` on the ID field, I use required - hence the "hack" in the `config/modules.js`.
2. I have a many-to-many association, which I cannot assign in the controller:
   I use:

   `await Tickets.replaceCollection(ticket.id, 'records').members(recordIds);`

I get an error:

`"Could not use one of the provided new records: Missing value for required attribute id. Expected a string, but instead, got: undefined"`

Has anyone been able to use similar (I'd say rather simple) setup?

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Can you please post a concrete example including a simple database schema, along with the code you are attempting to implement? Posting what you have so far will not only help us help you, but others who come along after.

Comment: edited the post, sorry for this